# Is there a way to find the Element of multiple Nodes of a XML-File by XPath?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to find the element of multiple Nodes in a XML-File by XPath. The Path to the Nodes is:

(/chapter/block/procedure/step/action/table/tgroup/tbody/row/entry/p/formfield)

I want to get the Element field_id from the Childnode formfield. There are multiple formfields in the XML-File. All have the same path but are located in different rows (/row).

I've tried:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("xmlfile.xml");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/chapter/block/procedure/step/action/table/tgroup/tbody/row/entry/p/formfield");
string attr = node.Attributes["field_id"]?.InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(attr);
```

This gives me only the field_id from the first formfield. I've tried multiple other ways to get every ID but I'm always getting a System.NullReferenceException. How can I get every field_id?

Comment: Can you share the XML?

Comment: The phrase "element of multiple nodes" doesn't mean anything to me. If you don't know the correct XML terminology then the best way to explain your problem is by example: show your desired input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easy if you share the sample XML. However you can try the below code sample using `XmlDocument`

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load("xmlfile.xml");
var result = xmldoc.SelectNodes("chapter/block/procedure/step/action/table/tgroup/tbody/row/entry/p/formfield/@field_id");
foreach (XmlNode item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

There is another approach using `XDocument` and `LINQ`

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");
var nodes = string.Join(", ", xdoc.Descendants("formfield")
                                  .Select(x => x.Attribute("field_id")));
```

**added below code based on comments**

Below is the code to read the comments in XML using `XElement`

```
var xdoc = XElement.Load("xmlfile.xml");
var comments = xdoc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>();

foreach (XComment comment in comments)
{
  //read comments here
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have a quick question. The XML-File contains comments in the formfields. How can I read the comment in the formfield?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xml linq and put results into a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication159
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict1 = doc.Descendants("formfield")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("field_id"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            //where attibutes may be repeated
            Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> dict2 = doc.Descendants("formfield")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("field_id"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```